# Jenkins multi master setup

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Hello I am new to Jenkins and was working on setting up multi master setup for HA (High Availability).

Do have the following queries:

1. In a multi master setup (active/passive) can we have 2 different OS flavours (1 RHEL/1 Ubuntu)? I am thinking the 2 will have different pkg build (binaries/plug-in) as per compatibility.
2. Also as we can have slaves with different OS [Windows /RHEL/Ubuntu] how would they use the plugins which are being installed on masters , which will be a different OS?

Comment: What do you mean by "[HA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ha)"? Hells Angels?

Comment: High Availability .

Comment: As long as you habe the same veraions of the binary and the plugins everywhere, should be no issue. Jenkins is a cross-platform Java binary. Note: as of 2.289.3 LTS, Docker images are Java 8 based, but weekly [2.307 is default Java 11](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2021/08/17/docker-images-use-jdk-11-by-default/), so expect next LTS to move up too?

Answer (score 0):

1. Jenkins' "executable" is `jenkins.war`, i.e. it's based on Java, so it should run equally on any OS that supports a compatible version of Java.
2. The same applies to Jenkins agents. See also [Using Jenkins agents](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/)  and [Setting Up a Jenkins Slave Node](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/jenkins-slave-node-setup).

See also [Jenkins, Java requirements](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/) .

Comment: So you mean to say, if we use the same Jenkins.war & Java version across multiple master and make sure the $Jenkins home directory is sun between both masters then we should be good if one of the master nodes goes down the other should work as master.

Comment: So we can have a Linux master and one windows masters for multi master setup for Jenkins , as we can use the same war which is written in Java and only need the Java to run ( need to make sure we have the same Java version on both nodes). Please correct me if I am wrong .

Comment: @Learner222 In theory – and mostly in practice – it'd be irrelevant which [Java version supported by Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/) runs on masters or agents since Jenkins' Java bytecode works always alike. There can be problems if you build or run tests on a Java version that's not supported by your code or your build tool. What do you mean by "_the $Jenkins home directory is **sun**_"? Is this meant to be "syn[chronized]"? If that applies, Q1: yes. Q2: yes, but you don't even need the same Java version for Jenkins, but maybe for your code/build tool.

Comment: When I say Jenkins’s home directory , I was referring to a place where all the Jenkins config files are located  and syncing that directly with 2 nd master [I mean to say backup ] and if the primary masters goes down then the second node will take the responsibility of master as it does have all the Jenkins config same as the primary one and resume the regular operations.

Comment: @Learner222 Yeah, I got that. It was only the sun/syn typo that I wanted to clarify.